# why writeParcelable and readParcelable messes up the data being passed?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

Like the title says, I don't know why when I try passing a object that contains another object that implements parcelable with `writeParcelable` and `readParcelable` messed up the data I pass?

by messed up I mean. the `ID` is read by `Name`, and `Name` is not being passed because there is nothing to receive the data, and the object may or may not be passed at all.

it is fine if I simply pass Strings, Integers, Double via parcelable, but not when I try to pass an Object which also implements parcelable.

Maybe I used the wrong method? to my understanding because the object contains another object which implements parcelable, I should use readParcelable and writeParcelable. But if it's wrong can anyone tell me which method I should use and how to use it?

Thank you in advance.

here are the parcelable Objects :

**First Object** :

```
public class Absen implements Parcelable{
  private String ID;
  private String Key;
  private String Name;
  private int Age;
  private Anak Anak;

public Absen(){
    //empty constructor
}

public Absen(String ID, String Key, String Name, int Age, Anak Anak)
 {
   this.ID = ID;
   this.Key = Key;
   this.Name = Name;
   this.Anak = Anak;
   this.Age = Age;
 }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
     protected Absen (Parcel parcel)
     {
      this.ID = parcel.readString();
      this.Key = parcel.readString();
      this.Name = parcel.readString();
      this.Anak = parcel.readParcelable(Anak.class.getClassLoader());
      this.Age = parcel.readInt();
     }

@Override
    public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel parcel, int i) 
    {
      parcel.writeString(getID());
      parcel.writeString(getKey());
      parcel.writeString(getName());
      parcel.writeParcelable(getAnak(),i);
      parcel.writeInt(getAge());
    }

@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    public static final Creator<Absen>  CREATOR = new Creator<Absen>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        @Override
        public Absen createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) { return new Absen(parcel);}

        @Override
        public Absen[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Absen[i];
        }
    };

   //Setters Getters....
  
}
```

**Second Object**

```
public class Anak implements Parcelable {
      private String ID;
      private String Key;
      private String Name;
      private String parentName;

  public Anak{
    //empty constructor
  }
  
  public Anak(String ID, String Key, String Name, String parentName)
  {
       this.ID = ID;
       this.Key = Key;
       this.Name = Name;
       this.parentName = parentName;
  }

  protected Anak (Parcel parcel)
    {
        this.ID = parcel.readString();
        this.Key = parcel.readString();
        this.Name = parcel.readString();
        this.parentName = parcel.readString();
    }

  @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i)
    {
        parcel.writeString(getID());
        parcel.writeString(getKey());
        parcel.writeString(getName());
        parcel.writeString(getParentName());
    }

   @Override
    public int describeContents(){ return  0;}

   public static final Creator<Anak> CREATOR = new Creator<Anak>() {
        @Override
        public Anak createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new Anak(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public Anak[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Anak[i];
        }
    };
}
```